# Does every Euler circuit pass through all vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

I have a question. In my homework I was assigned the following question:

Given a connected graph in which the degree of all vertices is 2, prove that this graph is a cycle. (Prove that there is a cycle in the graph that passes through all the vertices and edges).

My question is - isn't that obvious? I mean, I can't think of an example in which an Euler circuit *doesn't* pass through all vertices.

What am I missing? Could someone give me an example of an Eulerian graph that is not a cycle?

**EDIT: The question itself was answered, I would appreciate an example of an Eulerian graph that is not a cycle**

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Edited.

Comment: I'd consider a maximal path, show that it can be closed to a cycle, then argue that no additional vertex can exist because a path from it to a vertex in the cycle would create a degree $\ge 3$ vertex. --- But using Euler circuits, we know that one exists, and as every vertex of our graph is incident to at least one edge, th Euler circuit passes through it. -- Not every Eulerian graph is a cycle because not every even numbre equals two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a graph has 1 vertex with degree 2, the vertex has a self-loop edge back to itself. So the graph is a cycle graph.

Assume any connected graph with $k$ vertices, each vertex having degree 2, is a cycle graph, for some $k\ge 1$.

---

Consider connected graph $G$ with $k+1$ vertices, each vertex having degree 2.

Form graph $G'$ by removing a vertex $v$ and its neighbouring edges $e_1(v, v_1)$ and $e_2(v,v_2)$ from $G$.

The removed vertex and edge does not loop back into itself, i.e. $e_1\ne e_2$, because there are $k$ more vertices and the original graph is connected.

Join the original neighbour(s) of $v$ together with a new edge $e'(v_1,v_2)$; the graph $G'\cup \{e'\}$ is still connected, has $k$ vertices and each vertex now has degree 2. By assumption, this graph is a cycle graph.

In particular, in this cycle graph there are exactly two paths (each with distinct intermediate vertices and edges) from $v_1$ to $v_2$: one such path is obviously just $v_1, e', v_2$, and the other path goes through all vertices and edges of $G'$.

Breaking $e'$ and putting $v, e_1$ and $e_2$ back, there are still exactly two paths from $v_1$ to $v_2$, one being $v_1,e_1,v,e_2,v_2$, and one going through all vertices and edges of $G'$.

So the original graph $G = (G'\cup \{e_1,v,e_2\})$ with $k+1$ vertices is also a cycle graph.

Comment: Could you please further explain why it stays connected after removal?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. By removing a vertex $v$ and if the two neighbours $v_1$ and $v_2$ become disconnected, the set of vertices that $v_1$ connects to has a sum of vertex degree that is odd: $v_1$ has degree $1$ and all remaining vertices have degree $2$. Which is impossible and so it's a contradiction.

Comment: Can the same proof be used to claim that this is a simple circle?

Comment: Yes, my proof is about proving that the graph is a simple circle: all vertices visited exactly once, all edges visited exactly once.

Comment: Is it correct that every Eulerian graph is a cycle (non necessarily simple)?

Comment: "The term Eulerian graph has two common meanings in graph theory. One meaning is a graph with an Eulerian circuit, and the other is a graph with every vertex of even degree. These definitions coincide for connected graphs", so I would say... yes? [Wikipedia on Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)